# What is allocatestack.c:192 (advise_stack_range): assertion failed: freesize < size?

Tags: stack

I got this error while execute a program

Fatal glibc error: allocatestack.c:192 (advise_stack_range): assertion failed: freesize < size

Can you help to explain what is it?

Does this error occour because ofdeclaring a large array in the program?

Comment: Please state more information before posting the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.